# How to run a make file on save in VS Code - using go extension

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

How can I run a `make build` on save in VS Code on save event?

I can see that I can do something like the following.

```
{
    "go.buildOnSave": "workspace"
}
```

I guess the lack doc. is be cause  it is just basic VS Code - on setting a command.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I run a make build on save in VS Code on save event?

The [Build, Lint and Vet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go#_build-lint-and-vet) of the VSCode Go extension from Microsoft (v1.26) currently based on `go build`. You can choose the preset option for `package` (default), `workspace`, or `off`. See [vscode-go/goBuild.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/blob/master/src/goBuild.ts)

If you would like to have a custom build i.e. `make build` on your workspace, you can set [VSCode Custom Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) instead.